# getting "GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays" even though Xvfb display is present

Tags: docker, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I'm running selenium tests on headless firefox inside docker. For that I have installed firefox and Xvfb inside docker and export display using Xvfb command when I run the container.

The issue is, when I run the docker container locally, selenium is able to find the display but when I run the docker container on Jenkins it's giving "GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays"

For Xvfb I do

```
sh "export DISPLAY=:1"
sh "Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1440x900x24 &"
```

I checked available displays just before starting my test case using "ps aux | grep X". Below is the output

```
root        31  0.0  0.4 172336 18644 ?        Sl   16:36   0:00 Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1440x900x24
root       147  0.0  0.0  12812   980 ?        S    16:36   0:00 grep X
```